# SQL Server - How to Copy a Stored Procedure to Another Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure with the exact same path on multiple servers (live, development and test) and I would like to modify/alter it simultaneously. I was thinking this would happen via altering one and then copying that and overwriting it over the other two servers.

Would this be easily achieved?

Comment: We use RedGate's SQL Source Control for that sort of thing http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you can connect to all the environments from a single SSMS (unlikely in many companies because of security), you can register all 3 SQL Server instances in a single group and execute the same script on all instances simultaneously
   (refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx)
2. You can script out your stored procedure and use SQLCMD tool to execute it from file. Again, if you can connect to all instances from a single server, you can just duplicate the command in the script, but connect to multiple instances i.e. just use 3 SQLCMD lines

Comment: Ticked for keeping it Microsoft! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any schema compare tool, Such as [Red Gate SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/overview?utm_expid=108631182-44.qyHS2xLLSUShEIfTsYI15A.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.eg%2F)

Also check alternative tools to Red Gate: [Here](https://alternativeto.net/software/red-gate-sql-compare/)

Also youo can check this opensource tool: [Open DBdiff](https://opendbdiff.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Visual Studio can also compare databases - it's nowhere near as good or fast as Red Gate, but it does the job.

Comment: To apply changes to multiple targets, SQL Multi Script is probably a better bet that SQL Compare, which just does one-to-one unless you're using this programmatically via the command line.